# How can you get the numeric value of the Ed25519 public or secret key from gpg?

Tags: gnupg

I'm currently trying to find some interoperability between gpg and signify.
One attempt at this was exporting a subkey that's Ed25519 from gpg and using that as the public and private key for signify.

My thought process was: since both use Ed25519, I could just export the numerical values for the keys and then create a key for the program in the format it needs.

The issue I'm running into is that signify doesn't accept the key I generate. Compared to the keys that signify's only keygen generates, they're also always slightly longer (e.g. 73 vs 53 chars of b64).

Example for a public key:

- generated from gpg: `mDMEYOfb1RYJKwYBBAHaRw8BAQdAm33lkUfHyH81l6vQuRasADUlyAnYNZ+xhAE9GqLlzpU=`
- generated from signify: `RWRR4+XlAu/mPfcQ+50448/te//AT2Ym6S5rxmxP0H07m5Eny9XFMxDX`

I've tried
`gpg --export <keyID> | gpgsplit` with both a newly generated Ed25519 key and an Ed25519 subkey of an existing and then base64'd the public and private keys. This yields an 'invalid base64' error when running `signify -I -p pubkey` with the result.

I've also tried
using pgpdump (`gpg --export <keyID> | wsl pgpdump -i -l -m -p`), but that doesn't output any useful information.

I'm using

- https://github.com/nurse/signify via Debian WSL compiled with BSD libs linked
- Kleopatra / GnuPG for Windows
- https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/pgpdump via Debian WSL